# Don't create containers twice with docker-compose up and running docker run containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'd like `docker-compose` to use an already running container for `imageA` and not create it a second time when calling `docker-compose up -d`. The original container was run using `docker run`.

**Steps:**
I started a container with `docker run`, eg.

`docker run --name imageA -d -p 5000:5000 imageA`

I then call `docker-compose up -d` with a `docker-compose.yml` file that includes a service with the same name and image as the first container.

```
version: "3"
services:
  imageA:
    image: imageA
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  imageB:
    image: imageB
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
```

**What happens:**
`docker-compose` tries to create `imageA` and fails when it tries to bind port 5000 since container `imageA` has it bound already.

**Question:** How can `docker-compose` "adopt" or "include" the first container without trying to create it a again?

Comment: Can you please post the output of docker ps -a command?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is currently possible. If you compare the outputs of `docker ps` and `docker-compose ps`, you should notice that `docker-compose ps` does not show the imageA running, if it was started with `docker run`.

Docker-compose is only interested in the services that are defined in the docker-compose files, and it does not seem to use only the container names for that, but labels too, and you cannot add labels to running containers currently.

Other than that, the container started with `docker run` will also not be (at least by default) in the same internal network as those that are started with `docker-compose`.

So your best option would be either:
a) Removing the already running container from the compose-file.
b) Calling `docker-compose up -d imageB` to run only the individual service, so that the compose updates only that or
c) just stopping the already running container and starting it again with compose.

Docker containers should anyway be created in a way that it is easy and acceptable to just restart them when needed.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I was hoping to "fool" docker-compose. I was able to prevent it from creating a second container by using the same name format docker-compose would have created, ie: service_name_1. Also by including the labels that docker-compose would apply normally. I'm not yet able to have it simply say "up-to-date" though. I've tried setting the network to host. That did not work. The only other difference I can see when diffing a docker inspect before and after calling docker-compose is that the entry `"Volumes":` is populated with the binds.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--no-recreate` flag will prevent recreation of the container, if it already exists.

Example:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-example.yaml up -d --no-recreate
```